# Refresh a DBGrid VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dbgrid

I'm trying to refresh my DBGrid after I've clicked a button to delete all the data. I've tried refresh with no results. I've tried Refresh on the DBGrid1 and on the Data object and even on the Form.

Comment: Just clear your recordset and re-fetch the data.

Comment: how did you fetch the data the 1st time? call the method again, but dispose your recordset before calling it

Comment: When the page opens it binds the data automatically when you have the data object and the grid object. And if I close the form and open it again, it refreshes the data, but I need to manually do this somehow with the button click event.

Comment: Post your code, i'll edit it for you

Comment: Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

    DBGrid1.ClearFields '<--- I've tried this.

    DBGrid1.Refresh  '<--- And this.
        
End Sub

Comment: If I was doing this in .NET, I'd just put the dbgrid in an update panel.

Comment: In fact, you need to unbound the recordset to the grid, update the recordset and rebind it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just gave them a pop-up indicating the action was complete and then closed the form. If they want to look at the blank list, they can click on the button to view it again.